# ABPersonViewController Contacts List (Edit Mode)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm having some difficulty finding how to do my own implementation of the DONE button in EDIT MODE. My application requires that the people they select have valid E-mail addresses. If they do not, Edit Mode is shown and they are able to edit the email property in the Edit Mode. However, when they tap DONE, I would like to execute my own code rather than the standard, which is to just display the Display Mode for a given contact. I have not yet found a work around for this issue I'm having.

All assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can set one `BOOL` variable. When you will be in `edit` mode i.e if email address is not valid than set the text of button to `EDIT` and set value of that BOOL variable to `YES`.

And when email address is valid or editing is completed , set the text of button to `DONE` and set value of that BOOL variable to `NO`.

At the end by checking the value of that BOOL variable , you can do the action / operation you want to do.

i.e if `edit (YES)` do editing action and if `done (NO)` then do your standard action.

Hope this will help..